# How do I add a new edge loop when it conflicts with other edge loops?

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

I'm designing a shirt and I want a nice even stripe around the edges. My first approach was to draw the stripe on the UV map. But I saw a model designed by someone more experienced where the edges of the shirt were actually a different material. This seems like a cleaner, more flexible solution. (Eventually I'll bake down to a single texture map.)

So what I want to do is select the neck hole and arm hole and create a new edge loop, pulling it back to create a border. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working. It seems like existing vertices close to the edge of the shirt are preventing me from making a new loop there (I can make one, but very narrow). I'm guessing here but maybe the edge loop would cut some of my quads into n-gons and Blender doesn't want to do that. I can extrude and get what I want, but that requires actually extending the geometry. I just want new faces on the existing shape that create an even ring around the openings.

Ideas? What I'm thinking is I have to delete a bunch of existing edges to make room around these holes, THEN make the new edge loops, and then add additional cuts as necessary to get back some geometry in the middle of the shirt. But I was hoping there's a less manual way to do this.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: what is the problem if you select the edge around the neck and extrude inwards?

Comment: So you mean basically extending the shirt, making the neck hole a little smaller? Sure, I could do that. But I'm curious if there's a solution that doesn't change the actual shape. What if the shirt was tight around the neck and I couldn't extrude inwards? I did occur to me I could extrude back outwards to create facing that ALMOST overlap, but that seems like an ugly solution.

Comment: it depends on how big your stripe is supposed to be. Also do you need so many edge loops? It would facilitate if you simplify your topology but it all depends on your final goal...

Comment: I don't think I need so many edge loops? It's just a shirt for a medium-poly character. The way I got to where I am is by duplicating part of the character mesh, expanding it a little, and reshaping. That provides a nice fitted shirt but maybe gives me a weird topology. But honestly it looks logical to me; it's a gird of vertical and horizontal lines. What SHOULD it look like?

Comment: As long as you're not glad with your object, use Subdivision Surface modifier, and use much less edge loops, if you use so many edge loops, it makes all modification, like the one you're trying to do, rather tedious. At the end, apply the Subdivision Surface, or don't apply it if you don't need to (you need to apply it if you're making your object for a game for example)